# Port 8080 closed over VPN (Linux, OpenVPN, webpack, Node.js application). How to troubleshoot?

Tags: tcp, network

I am running a node application that uses webpack. The application starts and automatically selects the port 8080 on localhost:

[image]

The website works correctly on the browser on my machine. I want now to allow others to access it.

For this I want to make sure the port `8080` is reachable, so I add a firewall exception:

```
sudo uwf status
```

[image]

I check that the application is listening correctly:

```
sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

[image]

Then when I do nmap, the port scan fails for `8080` on my own VPN address.

```
sudo nmap 10.8.1.66 -p 8080
```

[image]

How should I troubleshoot this? Is this OpenVPN blocking the traffic?

Comment: Local host (127.0.0.1) is not 10.8.1.66. Other than that, host configuration questions are off topic here, you can try asking this on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application/service bound to the localhost loopback 127.0.0.1 can only ever be accessed on the same machine, using said loopback.

If you want the service to be available over the network you need to bind it either to a local interface's IP address or to the *unspecified address 0.0.0.0*, using all available interfaces.

Comment: Seems to be working by adding --host 0.0.0.0 to the webpack run command, thanks!